How to use a monostable 555 one shot circuit with a single dc rise at the trigger
In order to measure battery contact fidelity/degradation I am developing a "one shot" current measurement circuit. Basically, when a HV battery is plugged into a connector I will have a circuit that will need to close a switch for a very small period of time to short + and - battery terminals together through a shunt resistor, in order to measure current. that current value will till me if I am making good (debris free) contact through the connector.
My original idea was to use a classical implementation of a 555 one shot circuit to get an output pulse of 1ms however my trigger signal is a continuous dc 5v logic value with just one rise time (from zero, at circuit turn on.
I understand the the trigger waveform needs to be shorter than the output waveform (obviously not the case for me). Any advice with how to condition the trigger to work in this case? I have tried simulating with an RC differentiator but am not getting great results. Thanks!

What is the timing requirement for the delay since power up? In other words, does the pulse have to be trigger precisely at power up? Or is "1ms" the hard requirement? What is the device that requires the 1ms pulse? Have you considered supervisors?

The timing requirement from power on to the output 1ms 555 produced pulse isnt strict -  so no, it doesn't need to trigger precisely at power up but would be cool if it were <1s. 1ms is needed to close a transistor to read a shunt resistor across terminals of a battery. Im not too familiar with supervisors

I have about  5 different ways this could be done. But I have a strong feeling none of them are going to be what you really want. You should describe what you are really trying to do so you can get a real [system] solution. This line is what gives a way the XY problem: "1ms is needed to close a transistor to read a shunt resistor across terminals of a battery". I'm pretty sure this is not what you need to do.

Ill update the question with my end goal - thanks so much

Ive added further description on what Im trying to do. If I can find a supervisory ic that outputs a temporary low pulse once power supply is initialized I maybe good to use the 555 one shot still ..

Well presumably something has to sample the shunt voltage. And presumably that something knows when it has to sample the shunt voltage. So what's stopping that something from directly controlling the transistor for sampling the shunt for 1ms?

why do yo want to measure the resistance while the contacts are still moving?

I don't know if you really want to hear this ... but use an MCU. A little 6-pin PIC10Fxxx or ATtiny or summering like that. You can have exactly the pulse length you want from whatever trigger you have. Yes you'll have to write a few lines of code, but it'll take 1/4 the PCB area and probably cost less per unit.

you break my heart @brhans

Is this what you want?
LTspice simulation below.


Carl sir you are a gentleman and a scholar. Could you kindly explain to me the rationale behind using that npn, and the trigger circuit in general? Thanks
